# How to use VS Codes integrated terminal for debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I debug on VS code, it prints to the gnome-terminal. This makes it hard to keep track of both the code and the terminal sometimes. Is it possible to print to the integrated terminal rather than the external terminal ?

Comment: what commands were printing to the gnome-terminal?  print? were you using print to debug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To tell VS Code to use the integrated terminal with debugging you have to specify this in the launch configuration (`.vscode/launch.json`) using the `console` option. This setting specifies where to launch the debug target: internal console, integrated terminal, or external terminal.

```
"console": "integratedTerminal",
```

You can read more about various launch.json attributes in the [Code's documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes)