# Adding a preTask to launch.json command hides console output

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I want to create a task to debug a node proces.
For that it should start a build task.
So I add:

```
preLaunchTask": "npm: build:main",
```

On launch, I get the notification that this terminal will be reused by tasks and closing any button will close it.
When I do close it, I do not get a terminal with the debugging output. I only get my regular terminal back.

So I removed the task and launched again to see what happens.
Now no terminal at all opens up and I still only have the default terminal.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Note:
`presentation` is not set in the `launch.json` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43270170/9578667) fixes it. Adding this to the launch command shows the console again:

```
"console": "integratedTerminal",
```

It is weird that you need to specify the console implicitly in this case.